# how fio loads various io engines when it starts?

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, shared-libraries, libc

fio supports a whole bunch of io engines - all supported engines are present here : https://github.com/axboe/fio/tree/master/engines

I have been trying to understand the internals of how fio works and got stuck on how fio loads all the io engines.

For example I see every engine has a method to register and unregister itself, for example sync.c registers and unregisters using the following methods

`fio_syncio_register` : https://github.com/axboe/fio/blob/master/engines/sync.c#L448

and `fio_syncio_unregister` :
https://github.com/axboe/fio/blob/master/engines/sync.c#L461

My question is who calls these methods ?

To find answer I tried running fio under gdb - placed a break point in fio_syncio_register and in the main function, fio_syncio_register gets called even before main which tells me it has something to do with `__libc_csu_init`
and backtrace confirmed that

```
(gdb) bt
#0  fio_syncio_register () at engines/sync.c:450
#1  0x000000000047fb9d in __libc_csu_init ()
#2  0x00007ffff6ee27bf in __libc_start_main (main=0x40cd90 <main>, argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe608, init=0x47fb50 <__libc_csu_init>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffe5f8)
    at ../csu/libc-start.c:247
#3  0x000000000040ce79 in _start ()
```

I spent sometime reading about `__libc_csu_init` and `__libc_csu_fini` and every single description talks about methods being decorated with `__attribute__((constructor))` will be called before main, but in the case of fio sync.c I dont see fio_syncio_register decorated with `__attribute__`

Can someone please help me out in understanding how this flow works ? Are there other materials I should be reading to understand this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question. I couldn't figure out the answer looking at the source, so here are the steps I took:

```
$ make
$ find . -name 'sync.o'
./engines/sync.o

$ readelf -WS engines/sync.o | grep '\.init'
  [12] .init_array       INIT_ARRAY      0000000000000000 0021f0 000008 00  WA  0   0  8
  [13] .rela.init_array  RELA            0000000000000000 0132a0 000018 18     36  12  8
```

This tells us that global initializers are present in this object. These are called at program startup. What are they?

```
$ objdump -Dr engines/sync.o | grep -A4 '\.init'
Disassembly of section .init_array:

0000000000000000 <.init_array>:
    ...
            0: R_X86_64_64  .text.startup
```

Interesting. There is apparently a special `.text.startup` section. What's in it?

```
$ objdump -dr engines/sync.o | less
...
Disassembly of section .text.startup:

0000000000000000 <fio_syncio_register>:
   0:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
   4:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi
                        5: R_X86_64_32  .data+0x380
   9:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  e <fio_syncio_register+0xe>
                        a: R_X86_64_PC32        register_ioengine-0x4
...
```

Why, it's exactly the function we are looking for. But how did it end up in this special section? To answer that, we can look at preprocessed source (in retrospect, I should have *started* with that).

How could we get it? The command line to compile `sync.o` is hidden. Looking in `Makefile`, we can unhide the command line with `QUIET_CC=''`.

```
$ rm engines/sync.o && make QUIET_CC=''
gcc -o engines/sync.o -std=gnu99 -Wwrite-strings -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -g -ffast-math  -D_GNU_SOURCE -include config-host.h -I. -I. -O3 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -DBITS_PER_LONG=64 -DFIO_VERSION='"fio-2.16-5-g915ca"' -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DFIO_INTERNAL -DFIO_INC_DEBUG -c engines/sync.c
  LINK fio
```

Now we know the command line, and can produce preprocessed file:

```
$ gcc -E -dD -std=gnu99 -ffast-math  -D_GNU_SOURCE -include config-host.h -I. -I. -O3 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -DBITS_PER_LONG=64 -DFIO_VERSION='"fio-2.16-5-g915ca"' -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DFIO_INTERNAL -DFIO_INC_DEBUG engines/sync.c -o /tmp/sync.i
```

Looking in `/tmp/sync.i`, we see:

```
static void __attribute__((constructor)) fio_syncio_register(void)
{
 register_ioengine(&ioengine_rw);
 register_ioengine(&ioengine_prw);
...
```

Hmm, it *is* `__attribute__((constructor))` after all. But how did it get there? Aha! I missed the `fio_init` on [this line](https://github.com/axboe/fio/blob/master/engines/sync.c#L448):

```
static void fio_init fio_syncio_register(void)
```

What does `fio_init` stand for? Again in `/tmp/sync.i`:

```
#define fio_init __attribute__((constructor))
```

So *that* is how it works.

Comment: Wow I would have never figured this out, thank you very much for this effort.